# i can't save my template because of this SAXParseException. What's wrong?

Tags: blogger

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 132; columnNumber: 604; The reference to entity "view" must end with the ';' delimiter.`

I can't save my template because of this. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 132; columnNumber: 604; The reference to entity `"view"` must end with the ';' delimiter."

The character `&` should be encoded, changing `&` to `&amp;` should fix this.

In your case just change `&view` to `&amp;view`